# Undefined reference to libxml2 but works on another c file

Tags: c, xml, gcc, linker, libxml2

I tested [this](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/parse1.c) simple c file using libxml and it works fine, so I know that I have libxml installed correctly. However I tired running another file that has only this include statement `#include <libxml/xmlreader.h>` and I get all these linking errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so: undefined reference to `xmlParseMemory@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgnomevfs-2.so: undefined reference to `xmlFree@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrcasecmp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrdup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgnomevfs-2.so: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderRead@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgnomevfs-2.so: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderConstName@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgnomevfs-2.so: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderGetAttribute@LIBXML2_2.5.0'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgnomevfs-2.so: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderDepth@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgnomevfs-2.so: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderConstXmlLang@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeListGetString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgnomevfs-2.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewTextReaderFilename@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgnomevfs-2.so: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderNodeType@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetLineNo@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderName@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so: undefined reference to `xmlKeepBlanksDefault@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so: undefined reference to `xmlReaderForFd@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so: undefined reference to `xmlDocGetRootElement@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgnomevfs-2.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeTextReader@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgnomevfs-2.so: undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderConstValue@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
```

**EDIT**:
This is the command line I am using to compile the code:

```
gcc -g  `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 cairo libgvc glib-2.0 \
  gtksourceview-1.0 gnome-vfs-2.0 libgnomeprintui-2.2 libxml-2.0`  test-widget.c
```

for [this](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/parse1.c) file (simpler), this command works:

```
gcc -g  `pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml-2.0`  simplierFile.c
```

I also tried using the script `xml2-config` from the xmlsoft site but still same result.

I can't seem to find anything on google. I also have installed the `dev` files. If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks.

**EDIT2**:

Putting the source file before `pkg-config` doesn't work.

From the errors it seems that it is not linking libxml correctly.

**EDIT3**
The output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 cairo libgvc glib-2.0 gtksourceview-1.0 gnome-vfs-2.0 libgnomeprintui-2.2 libxml-2.0` is:

```
-pthread -DORBIT2=1 -I/usr/local/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0
 -I/usr/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/local/include
/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local
/include/libgnomeprint-2.2 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include
/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr
/include/graphviz -I/usr/include/gtksourceview-1.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include
/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include
/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomeprintui-2.2 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr
/include/gail-1.0  -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lgvc -lgraph -lcdt -lgtksourceview-1.0 
-lgnomevfs-2 -lgconf-2 -lgthread-2.0 -lgnomeprintui-2-2 -lgnomeprint-2-2 -lz 
-lgnomecanvas-2 -lgmodule-2.0 -lrt -lart_lgpl_2 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 
-lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype 
-lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lxml2
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact command line you're using to compile your code?

Comment: @larsks I added an edit.

Comment: @mihajlv okay, now what does the shell think that it's executing? unlike you, apparently, I cannot run pkg-config in my head

Comment: Does it work if you put the source file before the `pkg-config` invocation in the command line?

Comment: i guess the problem is `linking` order. The file which references the symbols in libraries should be put first(i know it sounds unintuitive). like `gcc main.c -la -lb etc`

Comment: @DanielFischer it didn't work still same result.

Comment: @tbert do you mean the whole output of pkg-config or just the libxml-2.0 outout, the second one seems to point to the right directories.

Comment: What is the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 cairo libgvc glib-2.0 gtksourceview-1.0 gnome-vfs-2.0 libgnomeprintui-2.2 libxml-2.0`?

Comment: @mihajlv I mean what is the actual command that the whole line gets expanded to; jesus, help us help you, man

Comment: @larsks I posted in the in the question as EDIT3. Thanks.